# Why does a mixture get warm in an exothermic reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics

The production of ethanol by fermentation is exothermic. My textbook says that the yeast stops working if the mixture gets too warm. Why would the mixture get warm if the reaction is exothermic?

Comment: I have edited your question, but in future, please use appropriate titles and tags: 1) if your question is about why the mixture gets warm, indicate so - the title you chose says that you are actually asking about why the fermentation stops. 2) if your question is about the exothermicity of the reaction, then it has nothing to do with organic chemistry, biochemistry, or alcohols. Instead, the thermodynamics tag would be more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In thermodynamics, we like to divide any situation into two parts, the system and the surroundings. In general the system is the part of the universe that is being studied while the surroundings is everything else that interacts with the system. Between the boundary of the system and the surroundings, energy and heat can be transferred (in an open system).

Now in fermentation, the yeast and glucose molecules are said to be the system while the surround water is the surroundings. Since the reaction is exothermic, this means that energy is moving from the system to the surroundings. Therefore the water should gain more heat energy which will increase its temperature.

However I doubt that the heat generated from the reaction is enough for the enzymes in the yeast to stop working. When I did this experiment we used a Bunsen burner to heat up the solution to approximately 35 degrees. So really what is going to cause the solution to heat up to above 45 degrees (this approximately where yeast begin to stop working) is that you keep the Bunsen burner on and keep heating it.

Comment: No worries, I am happy that I was able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

An exothermic reaction is a reaction whereby energy is released, typically in the form of heat. As fermentation is an exothermic reaction, it releases heat to the surroundings, i.e. the mixture warms up.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an exothermic process it releases heat which leads to the heat up of the mixture, second it stops working because in yeast fermentation requires enzymes to work. These enzymes have a optimal working temperature when the temperature rises above it they start to work slower (or above a critical temperature they denaturate and stop working for good, but I seriously doubt this will happen with heat coming only from the fermentation). 
I don't think it would stop working. It will be more of an equibilirium, because a slower reaction causes less heat which in return (provided the system is not isolated) will cool down which again speeds up the reaction.

Comment: Nice first answer +1 although it's also limited by yeast cells itself not only enzymes

Comment: @daveid So then the mixture heats up from the heat it produced during the reaction?  That's odd because the enthalpy of mixtures reduces during exothermic reactions. Also I'm assuming for the mixture to heat up, it must be in a closed system? Otherwise heat will be lost to the surroundings and not absorbed by the mixture.

Comment: This is actually an open system as energy and matter is freely able to pass between the boundary of the system and the surroundings. However it is the water that absorbs the energy from the reaction. And then it loses some of this energy to the surrounding air.

Answer (score 0):

We have something like this.

Reactants  ---> Products + Heat

Now by Le Châtelier's principle, we can say that if we provide heat to the reactant, (that is, raise the temperature) we are more likely to not get the product.

Comment: This reaction is enzymatic so this principle doesn't have much to do here.

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for the knowledge. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: Not necessarily, it probably has slight influence. Also might be a useful info for OP as he seems more interested about thermodynamics than mechanisms